# Writing a "for-while" loop in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

What's the Pythonic (2.7, 3) way to write a for-loop with a condition for stopping early?

For example

```
for item in lst:
    if not condition(item):
        break
    process(item)
```

Comment: I'm not looking to solve a specific problem.

Comment: Well that's not terribly helpful. The correct approach depends on things like whether you want to process all items `<= k` or until you reach the first one.

Comment: Original problem was finding the length of the common prefix of two strings. You can use `os.path.commonprefix`, but it made me wonder about ways of halting a `for` loop early.

Comment: The code up there isn't buggy (in that way), if that's what you're asking

Comment: I see; I have edited my answer to demonstrate using `takewhile` from `itertools` for that purpose.

Answer (score 2):

Your way looks great! I would normally write:

```
for i in lst:
    if i > k:
        break
    process(i)
```

(no need for explicit indexing). Or if you're feeling peckish:

```
map(process, it.takewhile(lambda i: i < k, lst))
```

Comment: The filter way doesn't stop on first failure.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`itertools.takewhile`](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/itertools.html#itertools.takewhile):

```
from itertools import takewhile

for item in takewhile(condition, lst):
    process(item)
```

From the documentation:

> `itertools.takewhile(predicate, iterable)`
>
> Make an iterator that returns elements from the iterable as long as the predicate is true.

---

To find your common prefix, for example:

```
def common_prefix(s1, s2):
    return "".join(a for a, _ in takewhile(lambda t: t[0] == t[1], zip(s1, s2)))
```

Comment: Looks good, but seems you are missing your `[]` on the list comprehension.

Comment: In a functional mood, I might prefer `return s1[:len(list(itertools.takewhile(operator.eq, s1, s2)))]`, though takewhile unfortunately doesn't take multiple iterables. I'll have to read up on argument expansion.

Comment: @Victory, that's a generator expression. Don't need parens for a genexp if it's the only parameter.

Comment: @leewangzhong - interesting, then why does `print ' '.join(a for a in xrange(3) if a < 4)` throw a `TypeError` ?

Comment: I can't see how the lambda takes two parameters. Should it be `lambda (a,b):`, and `lambda pair: pair[0] == pair[1]` in Python 3?

Comment: @Victory: .join requires a sequence of str. int not allowed. Use str(a) in the front part.

Comment: @leewangzhong yes, exactly - I *had* missed some brackets! Fixed to the version that works in both.

Answer (score 0):

Default answer: the way it's already written.

```
for item in lst:
    if not condition(item):
        break
    process(item)
```

Comment: It is not pythonic to iterate over (what I assume is) `n = len(lst)`; iterate over `lst` directly or `enumerate` it if you actually need the index.

Comment: `n` may have been precalculated as a bound. I didn't mean for the question to be about an actual list, though that's my fault.

Comment: Then you could do: `for index, item in enumerate(whatever): if index > bound or condition(item): break; process(item)`. This won't break if `len(whatever) < bound`.

Comment: I know. I was trying to make a simple example. I've simplified the example and updated the question.

Answer (score 0):

There have been attempts to establish a new syntax for list comprehension that incorporates the idea of `takewhile`.

In that format, the code can be written as [terrible way of list comprehension as one-line iteration without value, which will not be given in the answer itself for fear of collateral damage in impressionable minds].

For the problem of "common prefix of two strings", we have something like this:

```
def commonprefix(s1, s2):
    return ''.join(x for x, y in zip(s1, s2) while x==y)
```

Unfortunately, it seems that these attempts haven't been able to get anything agreeable: http://stupidpythonideas.blogspot.com/2013/07/syntactic-takewhile.html